# Sorting an array based on multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an unsorted array and an errors array

```
const arr = [
    {id: "BLR_123"},
    {id: "BLR_122"},
    {id: "BLR_125"},
    {id: "BLR_121"},
    {id: "BLR_126"},
    {id: "BLR_124"},
    {id: "BLR_127"},
    {id: "BLR_128"}
]

const errors = ['BLR_123', 'BLR_124', 'BLR_125']

const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.id < b.id) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.id > b.id) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})

console.log(sortedArr.map(({id}) => id))
```

I want to sort it based on 2 criteria

1. When id is there in error keep it on top
2. When id is not there sort based on alphabets

End result must be for about dataset.

```
[
    {id: "BLR_123"},
    {id: "BLR_124"},
    {id: "BLR_125"},
    {id: "BLR_121"},
    {id: "BLR_122"},
    {id: "BLR_126"},
    {id: "BLR_127"},
    {id: "BLR_128"},
]
```

is it possible to do it with single sort function?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check if `a.id` and `b.id` exist in errors. If both exist in errors or none of them exists in errors, sort alphabetically using `String.localeCompare()`. If only one exists in error return 1 or -1 accordingly:

```js
const arr = [{"id":"BLR_123"},{"id":"BLR_122"},{"id":"BLR_125"},{"id":"BLR_121"},{"id":"BLR_126"},{"id":"BLR_124"},{"id":"BLR_127"},{"id":"BLR_128"}]

const errors = ['BLR_123', 'BLR_124', 'BLR_125']

const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const aInErrors = errors.includes(a.id)
  const bInErrors = errors.includes(b.id)
  
  // if both are in error or both are not in errors
  if((aInErrors && bInErrors) || (!aInErrors && !bInErrors)) {
    return a.id.localeCompare(b.id) // sort alphabetically
  }
  
  if(aInErrors) return -1
  
  return 1
})

console.log(sortedArr.map(({id}) => id))
```